# Suitable Property of Rarely filled column of table inside SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a table like in the image:

[image: 'Notes' column is rarely filled!]

We have a column named **'Notes'** which is a rarely filled column.

**What is the best property to set for a column is rarely filled with SQL Server**

Comment: OT for SO - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). And I can forsee multiple problem you have yet to recognize - you have not properly normalized your table. Do you intend to update [Total Service Months] every day? Where is End Date - because employees don't stay forever?  Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming Running SQL Server 2016 and Later** ,
 You Need to set your column as **`SPARSE`** because:

1-Sparse columns are ordinary columns that have an optimized storage for null values. 
2-Sparse columns reduce the space requirements for null values at the cost of more overhead to retrieve nonnull values.
 
3-Consider using sparse columns when the space saved is at least 20 percent to 40 percent. 
4-Sparse columns and column sets are defined by using the CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statements. 
5-Sparse columns can be used with column sets and filtered indexes.

```
CREATE TABLE HR.Employees
    (
      NO int  Primary Key,
      ProjectCode int NOT NULL ,
      FullName varchar (50)  NOT NULL ,
      StartDate DATE  NOT NULL ,
      Salary int  NOT NULL ,
      TotalSeviceMonths int  NOT NULL ,
      TotalEOSInMonths int  NOT NULL ,
      TotalEOSAnount int  NOT NULL ,
      Notes varchar (150) SPARSE NULL,

    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to keep the column as variable character column, so that space is not wasted for rarely filled column. Specify a length to restrict junk values being filled into the notes fields. I am putting 512 here, just as a reference. You can decide the right length. If it is only English characters, go for `VARCHAR(512)`. I would suggest to have `NVARCHAR(512)` to allow for non-english characters also, so that if application goes international in future, it can be supported.

If notes can be of any length and can hold more than 8000 characters (if it is VARCHAR) and 4000 characters (if it is NVARCHAR), I would suggest to store them in either `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

**UPDATE**
As suggested by @Dale Burrell in comments, [SPARSE columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-2017) are a good fit for your needs. There are some limitations associated with SPARSE columns. Read about them and see whether they are fine for your needs.

Comment: Maybe mention `SPARSE` columns.